# Why is unique good practise in 1:1 relationships?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In the Grails Doc: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html
It says that adding a unique constraint in a 1:1 is good practise.
So if a face has one nose, we should do:

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]
    static constraints = {
        nose unique: true
    }
}
```

But Why? Surely, the constraint is implicit in the cardinality?

So why should we do it?

Comment: @joshua @ more than five ,i expected more technical ...but same nose for two face yes that is probably YES! but , how about the one who says this hasOne this is saying i will take care of your bala bla settings ...and are you sure what happens if you remove unique? if error comes no need for unique then?

Comment: @danielad The reason why simply using hasOne doesn't imply the unique constraint is because it's possible to have a N:1 relationship instead of 1:1 with the hasOne. Take for instance, a person and a house. Multiple people live in the house. Perfectly valid for a person to hasOne House and have the house id be used by multiple people. hasOne works for more than 1:1 relationships. That's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for putting the unique constraint is to ensure that two faces don't have the same nose. Since this is a 1:1 relationship the Id of the nose is kept on the face. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that only one nose knows the current face.

Without this constraint :

```
Face face = new Face();
Nose nose1 = new Nose();
face.nose = nose1;
face.save(flush: true);

Nose nose2 = new Nose();
face.nose = nose2;
face.save(flush: true); // no error, but in DB, nose1 and nose2 reference the same face_id
```